# Disable jQuery.validate's client side update

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-validate, client-side

I am using the [jQuery.validate](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) plugin for client side validation of forms using an error summary panel as opposed to each field having it's own error message, and it works great!  Although it seems counter-intuitive to me, I have a request to not update the error summary as the fields are satisfied.

So for example...I go to a blank form hit submit but I missed 3 required fields, let's say first name, last name, phone number.  The error summary at the top of the page reflects the error message for those three fields correctly.  As soon as type the first letter in any of the fields the error message drops out of the summary panel causing the form to shift up.  I'd like the messages to stay visible until the next submit.  I've checked through [the documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/) but can't seem to find a way to do this.

By the way this is an asp.net webforms application.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The validation plugin has options to disable revalidation on keyup and focusout. These are documented here: http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate

You most probably want

```
$(".selector").validate({
  onkeyup: false,
  onfocusout: false
});
```

Comment: Wow!  Not sure how I missed that, but thank you very much!!  Works as expected.

Comment: You're missing the comma (`,`) between the two options.  Also, would be good to mention that these options can only be set to `false` or to a custom function.  Setting them to `true` (default) will break the plugin.

Comment: @Sparky Thanks for spotting the missing comma, fixed. Concerning the option details: that's way I added the link to the documentation page. ;-)

Comment: Yeah, I know.  And if people read and understood the docs, we wouldn't be answering questions here.  Anyway, it was just my tip about how to turn a _technically correct_ answer into a _great_ answer.